Replace keyword in hql query and slowness
After adding replace operation to my hql query it became slower. How can I make it faster?
Products are transferred to my database with cronjob. My goal is to make a special change only to the name field without touching the sku and ean fields. The query must also find the product found when the product name "XDF 51241 L" is searched when "XDF51241L" is typed.
My query before adding the replace method:
where.append(" and (p.sku like :search or pd.name like :search or p.ean like :search ");
where.append(" or EXISTS(select 1 from ProductFeature pfe where pfe.product=p and (pfe.name like :search or pfe.value like :search))) ");

q.setParameter("search", "%"+productCriteria.getSearch()+"%");

After adding the replace method, my query is:
where.append(" and (p.sku like :search or pd.name like :search or p.ean like :search ");
where.append(" or REPLACE(pd.name, ' ', '') like :search ");
where.append(" or EXISTS(select 1 from ProductFeature pfe where pfe.product=p and (pfe.name like :search or pfe.value like :search))) ");

q.setParameter("search", "%" + productCriteria.getSearch().replaceAll("\\s+", "") + "%");

I used the replace method to search my query with or without spaces, but my query became very slow in terms of performance. How can I make my query even faster?

To fully understand your question and situation, we would have to look at the explain plan for the query above.  Sans that, I can comment that if the added call to REPLACE() be inside the WHERE clause, then this could kill any chance of your underlying database using any index available.  As a result, this could make performance worse.
One option here, to keep the same behavior as the first version, would be to simply store the pd.name field in the table with spaces removed.  So, you could add a new field to the pd entity called name_no_ws, and store there the name with all whitespace removed.  Then, refer to the name_no_ws field in your HQL query, thereby avoiding the need to call REPLACE().
